# Create Table Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, database

I received a MySQL data dump and am trying to insert the data into a set of temporary tables. The creation statement for the first table is shown below. When I run this I receive the error: "`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''temp_books'(  'ID'int( 11  )  NOT  NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  'start'varchar( 20  ) ' at line 1`". I've checked the documentation for MySQL syntax, and I don't see that the problem is.

```
CREATE TABLE 'temp_books' (
  'ID' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'start' varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  'customer_id' int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  'total_num' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'amount' double(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  'changed' timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY ('ID'),
  UNIQUE KEY 'start' ('start')
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4853 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't put single-quotes on your identifiers. If you're going to quote them use the "back tick" character (“`”). You can also use double-quotes but you have to specify that mode:

```
SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 2):

I've ALWAYS had issues with CREATE TABLE. Not sure why. Takes some trial-and-error.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_books (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  start varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  customer_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  total_num int(11) NOT NULL,
  amount double(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  changed timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  UNIQUE KEY start (start)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4853 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Does MySQL allow something like int(11)?

Comment: Yes. But I think it converts the declaration to an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete the quote marks, as well as the default for the changed field, as well as the default charset. Hopefully that won't affect the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of writing it that might work for some: (left away most of the columns for brevity)

```
create table temp_books
(
id int not null,
start varchar(255) null,
constraint six_cb_datasource_pk
    primary key (id)
);
```