# Error in CREATE TABLE syntax (1064) from SQLite dump

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem importing a dump from SQLite3 that I ran through a a script to strip out most of the conflicts, but some still remain.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 558774: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check 
the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 
use near 'MONTH NOT NULL,
    grade INTEGER,
    school INTEGER REFERENCES school(id),
   ' at line 4
```

It doesn't seem to be [a quoting issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454533/create-table-syntax-error), some hanging comma, etc.

Line 558774 is the `month` line in:

```
...
INSERT INTO census_block VALUES(1234,-0.32,1.47,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO census_block VALUES(5678,-0.43,-0.24,NULL,NULL);
CREATE TABLE history(
    sid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES student(sid),
    year YEAR NOT NULL,
    month MONTH NOT NULL,
    grade INTEGER,
    school INTEGER REFERENCES school(id),
    assigned_school INTEGER REFERENCES school(id),
    census_block INTEGER REFERENCES census_block(id)
);
INSERT INTO history VALUES(2319802,1991,9,9,1470,NULL,2468);
INSERT INTO history VALUES(2319802,1992,5,9,1470,NULL,3692);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a `Month` data type in MySQL.  Instead, use an `Integer` for the `month` column.

```
CREATE TABLE history(
    sid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES student(sid),
    year YEAR NOT NULL,
    month INTEGER NOT NULL,
    grade INTEGER,
    school INTEGER REFERENCES school(id),
    assigned_school INTEGER REFERENCES school(id),
    census_block INTEGER REFERENCES census_block(id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Month is not a legitimate data type. Change it to int or smallint i.e. month int